# Authlogic activation in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara, authlogic

I have a Rails app that automatically redirects from the home page to a login page if no user is logged in. I'm using Authlogic for authentication, Cucumber and Capybara for testing.

I have the following scenario:

```
Scenario: Start application
  Given I am not logged in
  When I go to the application web page
  Then I should see a login form
```

With the following test steps:

```
Given(/^I am not logged in$/) do
end


When(/^I go to the application web page$/) do
  visit root_path
end
```

(`Then I should see a login form` is a bit complex because it's wildcarded, but I'm not getting that far so it probably doesn't matter).

Following the guidance of http://laserlemon.com/blog/2011/05/20/make-authlogic-and-cucumber-play-nice/ I have created a file `features\support\authlogic,rb` containing:

```
require 'authlogic/test_case'

World(Authlogic::TestCase)

ApplicationController.skip_before_filter :activate_authlogic

Before do
  activate_authlogic
end
```

but when I run Cucumber, `visit root_path` fails with `Authlogic::Session::Activation::NotActivatedError: You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What capybara driver are you using -- the default in-process Rack::Test driver or a Javascript-capable driver?

Comment: Presumably the default one, because I'm not aware of having done anything to change it.

Comment: Not the issue with Javascript-capable drivers I was thinking of, then. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using exactly the same code with rails3 and today I discovered exactly the same error `Authlogic::Session::Activation::NotActivatedError: You must activate the Authlogic::Session::Base.controller with a controller object before creating objects` when I tried to run my cucumber tests with rails4.

What helped me was to remove lines `World(Authlogic::TestCase)` and `ApplicationController.skip_before_filter :activate_authlogic` and keep only this in `support/authlogic.rb`:

```
require "authlogic/test_case"

Before do
  activate_authlogic
end
```

Found this solution [here](https://github.com/jMarkP/Authlogic-Rails-3-Example/blob/master/README.md#user-content-4-user-session-model). For now it works, I'll check later if there are any side effects.